# Работа с потоками в C#

Tags: c#

Даны два текстовых файла одинаковой длины. Создать
многопоточное приложение для определения числа позиций, в
которых символы файлов отличаются (расстояние Хэмминга).
Количество символов в файлах может быть не кратно
количеству потоков.

Comment: Можно увидеть пример Вашего кода для решения данной задачи и конкретный вопрос что именно у Вас не получается?

Comment: @An0ther0ne впринципе не знаю как сделать это

Comment: Погуглить пробовали? Подучить матчасть?
В любом случае имею стойкое убеждение что никто здесь разрабатывать свой новый с нуля diff для вас не будет.

Comment: @blessed Что именно вы не знаете? Как работать с потоками? Не знаете что такое расстояние Хэмминга?

Comment: @iluxa1810 расстояние Хемминга знаю, а как написать программу нет

Comment: @An0ther0ne пробывал, ничего полезного

Comment: Покажите что вы пробовали

Comment: @Vearo просто гуглил, я не шарю в C#, вот и попросил помочь кого нибудь

Comment: А зачем вы решаете такую задачу если в нем не шарите? В чем смысл то? Может сначала начать шарить?

Comment: @Vearo задание в институте

Comment: Еще лучше) Зачем идти в профессию в которой нужно всю жизнь что-то учить, а вы по видимому учить совсем не хотите. P.s вряд ли вы дождетесь тут решения, вам скорее на фриланс биржу. Здесь помогают с проблемами в коде, а не пишут его с нуля за кого то

Comment: @blessed это значит, что вам преподавали c# в институте?

Comment: @tCode нет, нам самостоятельно дали это делать

Comment: @blessed конкретно на C#?) Что за институт не подскажите?)

Answer (score 1):

Нет ничего проще

```
Console.WriteLine(
    File.ReadAllText(@"C:\1.txt")
        .Zip(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\2.txt"), (x,y)=>x != y)
        .Where(x=>x).AsParallel().Count());
```

Comment: А что такой код маленький?